# Конструкция с союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

"Ты сладкая как мед". Я сомневаюсь здесь в запятой. Мне кажется, что сравнительный оборот тесно свзязан со сказуемым.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Душа должна находиться в постоянном восхищении, **пить сладкие, как мед, капли любви, веры, надежды…** [Светлана Васильева. Триптих с тремя неизвестными // «Октябрь», 2001]

**Я понимаю Розенталя.** У него были глубокие знания и удивительное чувство языка. Я представляю, как он сидит над рукописью и подбирает нужные слова, чтобы научить писать нас, но это невероятно трудно. Как вложить в стандартное правило истинный смысл русской речи, её музыкальность и неповторимость!

Он мог бы рассказать о фразовых ударениях, о движениях тона, о возможности выделить интонацией любое слово, будто **подчеркнуть** его ярким карандашом. Сказать, что **стихотворная речь отличается от прозаической** и запятые (нотные знаки) там ставятся немного по-другому.

**Но Розенталь пишет правила, втискивает музыку в их казенный стиль.** Пока надо писать так, а вот потом...

**Фразеологизмы?** Проверьте: внесен ***сладкий мед*** в списки фразеологизмов, где список? Ну вот же  он: **беречь как зеницу ока; труслив как заяц...**

Да, разные устойчивые сочетания называют этим словом, да только многие из них  в разных текстах меняют свою роль. **И каждый текст неповторим, каждому предложению противопоказан чисто формальный (равнодушный) подход.**

Розенталь сказал, Грамота подсказала, значит, не надо запятую ставить? Если для вас это просто безмолвные графические знаки, ни на что не влияющие, то, наверное, не надо. Объяснить-то легко: вот правило, вот ссылка. Всё, решено, все согласны, не будем ставить.

Но не так решаются задачи с союзом КАК, да и вообще все задачи.

**Где контекст? Это стихи, проза? Кто говорит эти слова?** Поэт декламирует стихи со сцены или Он  шепчет Ей: Ты любИмая, ты слАдкая, как мЁд...

**Простое сравнение или метафора?** Нет разницы.

А ну, кому чарджуйские дыни, **сладкие, как мед**, гладкие, как девушки, тают во рту! [Эльдар Рязанов, Эмиль Брагинский. Вокзал для двоих (1983)]

Из Нацкорпуса (сочетание ***как мёд***)

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA%E0%EA%20%EC%E5%E4&p=1

**Воздух был сладок, как мед.** Легкий мороз приятно пощипывал щеки. [А. П. Ладинский. Последний путь Владимира Мономаха (1960)]

**"Сладок, как мёд..."** Странно, запятая стоит. Ну да, это же краткая форма!  А вот в предложении "**Воздух был сладкий как мед**" запятую не ставим. Потому что фразеологизм. Железная логика!

Answer (score 3):

**Ты сладкая как мед.**

[**Д. Э. Розенталь**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=106) пишет (§ 42. Сравнительный оборот, п. 2 (посл.)):

Вопрос о пунктуации при сравнительных оборотах, в частности **при сравнениях идиоматического (фразеологического) характера**, не может решаться в отрыве от характера самих оборотов (…), состава устойчивых сочетаний, как он представлен в толковых и фразеологических словарях русского языка, и т. д.
И приводит список наиболее распространенных устойчивых сочетаний с союзом *как*, где присутствует оборот **сладкий как мед.**

А. Руднева (ОГЭ. Русский язык. Универсальный справочник) в статье "[7.5. Знаки препинания при сравнительных оборотах](https://books.google.ee/books?id=mhsZCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=pbliBZjvIz&sig=upmifBuDMtv_Rnmu5oyjPQrn9Mc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4yd7rwbPcAhXMJ1AKHbAWDmQQ6AEITjAF#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F&f=false)" подтверждает:

**запятая не ставится, если оборот представляет собой устойчивое сочетание** (беречь как зеницу ока; труслив как заяц; **сладкий как мёд**; нужен как воздух и т. п.).

*...ты ― супер, ты ― улет,

Ты жгучая как перец, ты сладкая как мед,

Ты вкусная как херес...*

*Ты сладкий как мед и горький как яд,

услада губам и отрава душе...*

Я бы не стала ставить запятую, основываясь на правилах.
Можно посмотреть ещё мнение [Грамоты.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4): запятая не нужна.

**Дополнение**

Контекста в вопросе нет, поэтому я рассматривала предложение **с точки зрения правил для обычной** (если можно так сказать) **пунктуации.**

Вот выдержка из [Большого толкового словаря](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x):
СЛАДКИЙ, -ая, -ое; -док, -дка, -дко; слаще; сладчайший.
1. Имеющий вкус, свойственный сахару, мёду и т.п. С-ие ягоды. Какой арбуз с.! **Абрикос сладкий как мёд.**

И логика, и опыт, и выводы @Jasmin достойны уважения.
И примеров с авторской (особенной, интонационной) пунктуацией предостаточно.

*От любви её я во хмелю.

Она сладкая, как мёд,

Розой алою цветёт,

Ну, а я огнём горю.*

*Ты ― сладкая как мед... Далекая ― как Марс.*

*Желаю вам жизни сладкой, как мед, беззаботной, как воскресное утро, удивительной и прекрасной, как далекие звезды...*

Резонно возникает вопрос: а зачем нам тогда правила и ссылки на них?

Comment: Вы действительно считаете, что в выражениях "вкусный как херес", "горький как яд", "жгучий как перец" и т.п. запятая никогда не ставится? Я сомневаюсь в качестве этих примеров.

Comment: Разве я написала, что **запятая не ставится никогда**? Я выразила свое собственное мнение и подтвердила его **тремя** источниками, которые достойны уважения. Надеюсь, что хотя бы в **_их** качестве_ Вы не сомневаетесь.

Comment: Я неудачно сказал "никогда", я имел в виду "во всех" (пусть только во всех перечисленных). Против остальных источников я не возражаю, мне только эти стихи показались сомнительными. (Я сам не уверен, как нужно ответить правильно на вопрос, хотя склоняюсь больше к другому мнению. В любом случае я не хотел придраться к ответу в целом, извините.)

Answer (score 1):

**Ты слАдкая, как мЁд.**

Это **сравнительный оборот**, в большинстве случаев он обособляется. А можно ли не обособлять?

Рассмотрим предложение без обособления: **Ты сладкая как мЁд.** Ударением выделено последнее слово. Этот вариант не будут считать ошибкой, автор может использовать обе формы.

И прочтение такое возможно, **да только оттенок смысла для метафоры получается сомнительный.** Как будто сладкий вкус предполагался и не вызывал сомнения, но оказался очень сладким, просто приторно-медовым. И к кому здесь вообще обращается автор?

**Пример:**

В дороге ели чудесные дыни ― такие, которых ты никогда не ела ― ароматные, как ананас, и **сладкие, как мед.** [Лидия Вертинская. Синяя птица любви (2004)]

Для сравнения можно привести пример без обособления:

Так она делала несколько лет подряд и добилась, что арбузы стали **сладкие как мЁд.** [Николай Носов. Приключения Незнайки и его друзей (1953-1954)]

Здесь **сладкие** на вкус арбузы дополнительно приобрели **вкус мёда**.

Comment: А можно к Вам еще один вопрос?

Comment: В ваших примерах "сладкий" имеет буквальный смысл. В вопросе же составляющая "как мёд" входит в состав комплимента-метафоры и потому не может быть отброшена. Нет ли готовых примеров с подобным смыслом?

Comment: "Готовых" - это взятых у авторов?

Comment: Да, это вопрос к Jasmin.

Comment: @Alex_ander Вот пример из пособия для учителя "Трудные вопросы синтаксиса": "Речь сладкая, как мёд, из уст его текла" (И.А. Крылов). Там как раз отрывок про эти "как", но гугло-книги показывают слишком мало. (Поддерживаю ответы Jasmin.)

Comment: Но "**сладкая речь**" - отдельное устойчивое сочетание, в отличие от "ты сладкая". В исходном выражении законченным сочетанием выступает другое: "**сладкая как мёд**".